# Back Cover with summay/information

Tags: double-sided, scrbook, covers

I have a double-sided document (scrbook) and wanna insert a back cover. Right now the last page is filled with content (last page of my bibliography) - I expected, that Latex would but at least two empty pages after the last chapter.

So how can I insert an empty (unnumbered) page followed by another (unnumbered) page with some text (e.g. webpage at the bottom) on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a double sided KOMA-Script document you can use `\cleardoubleevenpage` before the back cover. On the back cover page use `\thispagestyle{empty}` or `\pagestyle{empty}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}%only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\Blindtext
\cleardoubleevenpage
\thispagestyle{empty}% or \pagestyle{empty}
Back cover
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you have changed the default value of option `cleardoublepage` to eg. `plain`, then you have to use `\cleardoubleevenemptypage` or `\cleardoubleevenpageusingstyle{empty}`

Example:

```
\documentclass
  [cleardoublepage=plain]% blank pages use page style plain
  {scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}%only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\Blindtext
\cleardoubleevenemptypage% or \cleardoubleevenpageusingstyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}% or \pagestyle{empty}
Back cover
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had to add:
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\url{www.xyz.org}